# TSQL: Is there a way to call a function that receives and returns a table inside a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create a function `CalculateTotal()` that receive a list of value, percentage and returns me a calculation and the total percentage.

I need to call this function for each of the rows of another SELECT, is this possible?

Something like:

```
SELECT CalculateTotal(SELECT value, percentage FROM TABLE2 WHERE field = other_field), other_field 
FROM Table1
```

I've created a table function for `CalculateTotal`, but I need to first create a variable of a user defined table data type, and then pass that variable to the function, in that case I'll need to use a cursor to call that function for each row of my query, I want to know if there is some other way to do it, or if I definitely will need a cursor.

I have the following items:

- A table of courses (`course_id`, `course_name`)
- A table of students (`student_id`, `student_name`)
- A table of student notes in a course (`note_id`, `note_value`, `note_percentage`, `course_id`, `student_id`)
- A table data type `Notes` (`note_value`, `note_percentage`)
- A table-valued function `CalculateTotal()` that receives a `Notes` table type and returns two values (`final_note, @percentage`)

What I need is for each student and course to call the `CalculateTotal` with the notes of that student in that course, so it would return something like this:

```
course_id   | student_id   | final_note (from function) | percentage (from function)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 1            | 3.2                        | 0.8
1           | 2            | 5.0                        | 1
```

Comment: you might find this useful: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2008/table-valued-parameter/

Comment: That is exactly what I did, my question is how to call that function for each of the rows of a query (if there is another alternative to creating a cursor)

Comment: We have no idea where those numbers came from. Can you please share the definition of the function and some sample data that generates that output?

Comment: You don't need a cursor to run a function for each row in a query - look at `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: I can't because the function receives a table type, so I need to declare it first

Comment: Sorry everyone for the lack of clarity in my post, I will try to repost it with a clearer explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY?

```
SELECT x FROM dbo.t1
  CROSS APPLY dbo.TableValuedFunction(t1.column) AS t2;

SELECT x FROM dbo.t1
  OUTER APPLY dbo.TableValuedFunction(t1.column) AS t2;
```

Comment: Nice, but how can I do that if I need to pass a user defined table type to the function?

Comment: Uh, do you mean the function takes a TVP as a parameter? `... dbo.FunctionName(@tvp)`? I think we need more context to solve your problem. What data is in the TVP, what table does the function look at, and are any other tables involved? Can you share the definition of the function, the TVP, and any other tables that are involved, as well as sample data and desired results? I think there are some terminology barriers here that are making it hard to answer your question based solely on word problems.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to put more detail, tell me if there is something missing, thanks

Comment: @Escobar5 It's not, please provide more info.